# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 

Tags: c++, function-pointers

My problem this time is assigning a function to a pointer to function. I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
 private:
   bool dofunction() {return true;}

protected:
   bool (*ptf) (); 

public:
   MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass
{
    ptf = dofunction;   //// error 
}
```

but if I use a function outside the class it compiles:

```
bool function()
{
    return true; 
}

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    ptf = function;   //// OK
}
```

any help?

---

aha!! 
thank you

I used `static` keyword.

Comment: The function types are incompatible... one is a member function (with the implicit `this` parameter) and one is not a member function.

Comment: The question is unclear please consider fixing grammar and tidying code.  Also please select an answer.

Answer (score 5):

For class member function you need to use [pointer to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1):

```
bool (MyClass::*ptf) () ;
```

It should be assigned as,

```
ptf = &(MyClass::dofunction);
```

Also note, that now you **cannot** assign `ptf` to non-class functions. It's a different type altogether (even though syntax look same).

Answer (score 0):

The first one is of type `bool (MyClass::*ptf) ()` .. you need to specify the class it's in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
bool (MyClass::*ptf)();
```